# How to read this attributes in this xml using PHP?

Tags: php

http://idragonlk.com/channels.xml

This is the xml.

What wanna be is read this channel and programs in a loop.

```
<?php 
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("channels.xml");

$xmlObject = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel');
$itemCount = $xmlObject->length;

for ($i=0; $i < $itemCount; $i++){
    $title = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('display-name')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    print "Finished Item $title n<br/>";
}
?>
```

I have tried this. But it prints the txt values. I'm unable to get attribute values.

Wanna get value of

channel id=' '

lang='' of display-name

icon src='' value

program start ='' value

program stop = '' value

program channel = '' value

in program rating value

Plz can anyone help me?

Comment: answered this Question as possible as short. try with below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Maybe Helpful to you.

```
<?php

/*CURL PHP library to get file contents*/
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://idragonlk.com/channels.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
/*End*/

/*Takes a well-formed XML string and returns it as an object.*/
$XMLOutPut = simplexml_load_string($output);


//$channel_list = getChannel_list($XMLOutPut);
//$programme_list = getProgramme_list($XMLOutPut);

echo "<pre>";print_r(getChannel_list($XMLOutPut));
echo "<pre>";print_r(getProgramme_list($XMLOutPut));
exit;

/*Function to fetch channel and programme*/

//channel
function getChannel_list($mainObj){$Result_List =  array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($mainObj->channel);$i++){
        $Result_List[] = objectToArray($mainObj->channel[$i]);
    }
    return $Result_List;
}

//programme
function getProgramme_list($mainObj){$Result_List =  array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($mainObj->programme);$i++){
        $Result_List[] = objectToArray($mainObj->programme[$i]);
    }
    return $Result_List;
}

//Convert Object to array.
function objectToArray($obj) {
    if (is_object($obj)) {$obj = get_object_vars($obj);}

    if (is_array($obj)) {return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $obj);}
        else {return $obj;}
}
?>
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4seven UK
                )

            [display-name] => 4seven UK
            [icon] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [src] => 4seven UK.png
                        )

                )

            [url] => http://www.tvguide.co.uk
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5STAR UK
                )

            [display-name] => 5STAR UK
            [icon] => Array
            ......
            ......
```